# CPLEX in Java, how to check a IloNumVar is less than zero inside of model?

Tags: java, cplex

In the objective function part,i want to use/include only the negative decision variables such as
if(IloNumVar < 0)..., however, I can't use that notation. How can I check this alternatively? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could rely on IloMin

```
public IloIntExprArg IloMin(const IloIntExprArg x, const IloIntExprArg y)
```

Let me use OPL to show this:

```
dvar int x in -4..4; 
dvar int y in 5..5;


minimize minl(x,0)+minl(y,0);
subject to
{
  
}
```

gives objective -4